# Prevent form submission till SweetAlert is true

Tags: jquery, forms

I want to do some actions when a form is submitted. But first i want to check if the form should delete anything. The thing is, i cant get my form submitting again. How do i fix this?

```
$('body').on('submit', 'form', function ( e )
        {
            let self = $(this);
            if ( self.find('input[name="_method"]').val() == 'DELETE' )
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                swal({
                        title: window.translations.delete_item_title,
                        text: window.translations.delete_item_content,
                        type: "warning",
                        showCancelButton: true,
                        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                        confirmButtonText: window.translations.delete_item_confirm,
                        cancelButtonText: window.translations.delete_item_cancel,
                        closeOnConfirm: false
                    },
                    function (input)
                    {
                        if(input){
                            $(this).submit();
                        }
                    });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your SweetAlert complete function `this` will be scoped within that function, not the original submit function. When you submit, you are creating a variable called self - you need to call the `.submit()` method against this near the end of your code:

```
if(input){
    self.submit();
}
```

Also I would personally recommend that private members such as the `self` variable are given underscore prefixes; `_self`. This removes a degree ambiguity.